# Algorithm to determine dependencies

Tags: algorithm, sorting

What algorithm would I use to determine which swaps are dependent on another?

Rules

1. Swaps can happen in parallel unless there is a dependency
2. Swaps happen in batches, eg. trades that are dependent on another
   must wait until the dependent swap has processed from the previous
   batch.

Here's an example

- Johnny has $100, and 5 apples
- Fern has $150 and 3 oranges
- Bill has $0 and 3 peaches

Queue of swaps

A) Fern trades $50 for 5 apples from Johnny

B) Johnny trades $140 for 2 peaches to Bill

C) Fern trades $10 for 1 peach to Bill

Actual dependencies

A -> B

C

Once I know the dependencies I can use a topological sort to determine which order to process in which batch. How would I write code to automatically determine the dependency?

If balance sufficient in current state, process swap, if not find which swap needs to be completed first.

Comment: I don't think the construction of a dependency tree is possible. For example, Fern has $20. Transactions queued: A) Fern trades $10 for something B) Fern trades $10 for something C) Fern trades $10 for something. Transactions A and B can be processed in parallel, and C has to wait. But what does C depend on? The answer is that C depends on any transaction, or combination of transactions, that gives Fern $10. I don't see how that can be expressed as a simple dependency.

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly sure that trying to organize this to run in as few batches as possible will be NP-complete.  However a greedy solution will give fairly good solutions, fairly easily.

What I mean by that is that you can run through all of the swaps, adding the ones to the current batch that have available resources to run.  Run those swaps.  Repeat for the next batch.  Continue until all swaps are used up.